# Laravel Authentication logout error

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am using custom laravel authentication with a table that doesn't have remember token and timestamps and when I logout using `Auth::logout()` I get this error:

> Error Message : ORA-00904: "UPDATED_AT": invalid identifier
>   Position : 52
>   Statement : update ums.users_password set remember_token = :p0, updated_at = :p1 where user_sys_id = :p2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puts this 2 functions in your **Model** class, that will override functions in `Authenticatable`.

```
public function setRememberToken($value)
{
    return;
}

public function getRememberTokenName()
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: the weird thing that it does actually log me out but this error prevent the redirect to the ('/')